# How to scale from CVImageBufferRef -- or -- why didn't setPixelBufferAttributes work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, nsimage, quartz-core

I am capturing video off the camera (Macbook Air, OSX 10.9.5) via `QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput` and processing it but I need to scale the image coming in.  For whatever reason the image passed back to me is not the size I requested when setting the pixel buffer attributes:

```
   [mVideoOutput setPixelBufferAttributes:
       [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSNumber numberWithDouble:width], (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithDouble:height], (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
            nil]];
```

I'm getting an image back that is twice the size I requested.

**What is the most efficient way for me to scale the image to half its size?**

Or even better....

**Why is setPixelBufferAttributes not working as it should?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `setPixelBufferAttributes` was ignored on the first request so in the callback when the image is received from the camera I check the size and issue the request again if not correct.  This seems to have fixed the issue.